# Non Recursive Index CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

As a CosmosDB (SQL API) user I would like to index all non object or array properties inside of an object.

By default the index in cosmos `/*` will index every property, our data set is getting extremely large (expensive) and this strategy is no longer optimal. We store our metadata at the root and our customer data wrapped inside of an object property `data`.

Our platform restricts queries on the `data` path to be value type properties, this means that for us to index objects and arrays nested under the `data` path is just slowing down writes and costing RUs to store but never getting used.

I have tried several iterations of index policies but cannot find one that fits. Example:

```
{
    "partitionKey": "f402a704-19bb-4f4d-93e6-801c50280cf6",
    "id": "4a7a11e5-00b5-4def-8e80-132a8c083f24",
    "data": {
      "country": "Belgium",
      "employee": 250,
      "teammates": [
        { "name": "Jake", "id": 123 ...},
        { "name": "kyle", "id": 3252352 ...}
      ],
      "user": {
        "name": "Brian",
        "addresses": [{ "city": "Moscow" ...}, { "city": "Moscow" ...}]
      }
    }
  }
```

In this case I want to only index the root properties as well as `/data/employee` and `/data/country`.

Policies like `/data/*` will not work because it would then index `/data/teammates/name` ... and so on.

`/data/?` => assumes data is a value type which it never will be so this doesn't work.

`/data/` and `/data/*/?` and `/data/*?` are not accepted by cosmos as valid policies.

Additionally I can't simply exclude `/data/teammates/` and `/data/user/` because what is inside of `data` is completely dynamic so while that might cover this use case there are several 100k others that it would not.

I have tried many iterations but it seems that options don't work for various reasons, is there a way to support what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This indexing policy will index the properties you are asking for.

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/partitionKey/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/data/country/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/data/employee/?"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer, the question states that this is just an example object, 1 of 100k+ unique data shapes that might be present. We need to index anything that is under the data path for all of those 100k+ data objects however due to the large size of the data set we do not want the indexing to be recursive. It should index all properties inside of the `$.data` path that are not of type array or object.

Comment: No such thing exists in Cosmos DB. If you want to exclude something from being indexed, add the path to it in excludedPaths in your indexing policy. If you have no idea what's those paths are going to be, then not sure anyone can help you. The fact that you're trying to do this in the first place is something of a red flag. If the issue is that the arrays keep growing in size then that's an issue with your data model. There are rules for when to embed vs reference in Cosmos DB. Unbounded arrays should be avoided as well as extremely large documents.

Comment: The data is not growing unbounded, there are just many different shapes of data. This is the whole reason for using a document db, you don't have to have a fixed schema. Recursive indexing with the wildcard is a nice feature that cosmos offers but having some way to say how deep it should go seems like it would be a worth while improvement, similar to the indexing precision feature that was added. That is why I am asking the question because after carefully reading the docs I could not find the solution but you never know what you might miss :)

Comment: You can make feature requests of the team here, https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/3002b3be-0d25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858